# put a figure into the list of table?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I've copied a table from another .pdf and inserted it as a figure in my latex code. Is there an easy trick to consider his label, his caption everything as it was a table? And of course I would like it to appear in the list of table instead of in the list of figure.

Tks!

Edit: I've tried something like this:

```
\begin{table}[h!] 
\begin{figure} 
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{fig.png} 
\end{figure} 
\caption{tab} 
\label{tab} 
\end{table}
```

but it gave me this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \includegraphics
```

Comment: put it in a table environment instead of a figure environment

Comment: I've tried something like this:

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{fig.png}
\end{figure}
\caption{tab}
\label{tab}
\end{table}

but it gave me this error
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \includegraphics

Comment: well if you tried something and it didn't work then say what you did and someone can help.

Comment: Just remove the `figure` environment, you don't need that to use `\includegraphics`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not important what contents is inside a float environment. The name `table` or `figure` is only recognized by the `\caption` macro. It has to know what type of caption has to be used.

```
\begin{table}[h!] \centering
\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{fig.png} 
\caption{tab} 
\label{tab} 
\end{table}
```