# Should a float with two or more tables be considered a table or a figure?

Tags: tables, floats

This is maybe a soft question, but I think it is still relevant to proper typesetting with LaTeX.

I have a float with two or more tables. Should this be a figure or a table?

What if I have an arrow from one table to another, indicating some relation between the two tables?

Comment: Why should it be considered as a figure? A table is a table... If you include an image of table it is logically a table still...

Comment: If they are still tables, call them table(s). But if you only want to figure the relation between the tables, call them a figure.

Comment: I don't see why this got put on hold as opinion based, the posted (and accepted) answer only discusses facts about the latex float implementation. (@Schweinebacke)

Comment: ...I still think this is opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle IMHO the OP already recognized that `figure` can contain not only images and `table` can contain not only tabulars. So IMHO the question does not discuss facts about the float implementation but opinions. BTW: Otherwise it would be a duplicate, e.g., of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187512/put-a-figure-into-the-list-of-table and should be closed too. Nevertheless, this is my opinion. You have the power to have another one.

Comment: @Schweinebacke that one's about the not in outer par mode error (and the answer doesn't address the different effect you get by putting a table in a table or in a figure environment) but anyway I only pinged you in case you wanted to retract the close vote, if you don't that's fine, I see Werner just commented that he agrees with you as well:-)

Comment: @Schweinebacke You are right, I was not discussing facts about the float implementation. I guess I was asking for educated opinions indeed. I have to admit that I chose the answer partly because I saw this question not going anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important distinction between `figure` and `table` is not the content. You can put a `tabular` in a `figure` or `\includegraphics` in a `table`.  The important distinction is that LaTeX keeps all floats of the same class in order.

So while (using `caption` package) you can put a table in a `figure` environment and give it a table caption with `\captionof{table}{Zzzz}` the typesetting of the tabular-in-figure  will be just as if you had used `table` but LaTeX will not ensure that it stays in sequence with `table` environments, so it may be that if floats past a table meaning table 1 gets typeset on a later page than table 2.